# Proving a Triangle relationship

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

[[image: Figure <span class=]$1$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2aYGl.png)

Given $\triangle ABC$, we have$$c=a\cos B+b\cos A\tag{1}$$

Where $a=BC$, $b=AC$ and $c=AB$.

> **Question:** How do you prove the relation?

I started with$$\begin{align*} & CD=a\cos B\\ & CD=b\cos A\end{align*}$$
So adding them up gives$$2CD=a\cos B+b\cos A$$However, what's confusing is how $2CD=c$ for the equation $(1)$ to hold.

Comment: looks like you have got your cos & sin muddled ?

Comment: Maybe $CD = a\sin B$?

Comment: The correct relation is $CD=a\sin B=b\sin A$, which gives the law of sines: $\frac{a}{\sin A}=\frac{b}{\sin B}$.

Comment: This triangle relationship looks complicated...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are mistaken. We have $$\begin{align*} & CD=a\sin B\\ & CD=b\sin A\end{align*}$$

Please review  [the definition of the trigonometric functions, as provided in this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions), to see why this is so.

This is why you're not getting an answer. To prove the property, we use $$\begin{align*} & BD=a\cos B\\ & AD=b\cos A\end{align*}$$
In the diagram provided. Adding the two, we have $$c=a\cos B+b\cos A$$

Comment: Wow... How did I make that mistake?!?

Comment: @Frank To be frank with you, I have made those kinds of mistakes before too. It's fine. Just be sure to never make it again.

Comment: **NOTE** If you're wondering why I did not divide the cases of when the angle is obtuse and acute seperately, I was assuming the diagram was given. In the triangle,

Comment: @S.C.B. isn't it a bit harsh to say "Just be sure to never make it again"?  :P

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Is that harsh? I have no idea.

Comment: Well, it has a final tone, like a "do or die and be disgraced forever" type of tone.

Comment: @S.C.B lol I get your joke!! :P

Answer (score 2):

Let $B>90^{\circ}$.

Hence, $$c=b\cos A-a\cos(180^{\circ}-B)=b\cos A+a\cos B$$
The case $B\leq90^{\circ}$ is obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Using [the Law of cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines) : $c=a\cos B+b\cos A \Leftrightarrow c=a \frac {a^2 + c^2 - b^2}{2 ac}+b\frac {b^2 + c^2 -a^2}{2bc} \Leftrightarrow 2c^2=2c^2$